# Color of the action bar in tabview

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, material-design

how to change the color of action bar in each tab in my view pager?
I want to change the color of action bar with each tab click on the view pager

Comment: use ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener on your view pager and then change the color programatically

Comment: can u please elaborate a little

Answer (score 0):

You can add an on page change listener to your view pager, which is then called on each swipe. Once the user swipes, you can check the position of the view pager and change the action bar color accordingly. Here is one way how you can do it.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.my_viewpager); // assumes your view pager id is my_viewpager
  viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
      // change action bar color here depending on the position...
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: @Anshulshankar Then consider accepting this answer, please :)